# Chat dashboard pagination not working

Tags: bug, chat

When I hit a chat link first time, https://chat.stackoverflow.com and clicked on the *Next* button (pagination area), it redirected to an error page:

> https://chat.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/

I just wanted to give the failed scenario which I encountered, for the Stack Exchange team, so they can make it more robust application for all users.

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue here.

Comment: This is happening now when I am clicking continuously on "Next" button
Assuming network latency or slow network causes this issue, Please try to hit continuously to reproduce it.

Comment: No repro here as well. Why do you need to browse all the rooms? You can just search for the room you want.